# In ExtJS 5.1, how do I style a floating container with SASS?

Tags: extjs, sass, extjs5

When my container is not floating, my SASS works good:

[image: non-floating container with SASS applied]

But when I add the float config, the SASS styles are gone:

[image: floating container with SASS NOT applied]

So how to style floating container? I'm fairly good at ExtJS styling, but no matter what selectors I use in my sass file, the styles are never picked up.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the generated HTML when the container is floated and not floated, and it seems when floated the container is placed in the viewport.

So I moved my SASS in the Application.scss file and now the styling works:

MY_APP_PATH/sass/src/Application.scss

Problem solved.